# touch outside dialog both close it and trigger OnItemClickListener in parent

Tags: android, listview, gridview, dialog

I have a `GridView` which display a small custom dialog (with data about that cell) when a cell is clicked.
Dialog is shown in a `OnItemClickListener()` set for the `GridView`.

Dialog has `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`.
Right now:

- I click on a cell
- dialog is shown
- I click outside the dialog on another cell
- dialog is closed
- I click again on that another cell
- a dialog for the new cell is shown

I would like for a single click outside a dialog to:

- close this dialog
- show the dialog for the new cell (trigger `OnItemClickListener` of the `GridView`)

I was looking at different combinations of
`onInterceptTouchEvent()
onTouchEvent()
dispatchTouchEvent()`
but I wasn't able to accomplish that.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

we can't perform such kind of operation in android,

because while your dialog is open at that time your activity is in onPause() mode and the most forGround view is your dialod,

you must have to go back in your activity view (means start onResume()/onCreate()) then after you perform your task for open the second dialog.

Comment: I know an android app (calendar) that does it.

Comment: which one default calender ...? may i have version of android and application name please ?

Comment: Android 4.4.2 and application where I saw this behavior is Business Calendar https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal&hl=en